# JavaScript: How to create a new instance of a class without using the new keyword?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, instance

I think the following code will make the question clear.

```
// My class
var Class = function() { console.log("Constructor"); };
Class.prototype = { method: function() { console.log("Method");} }

// Creating an instance with new
var object1 = new Class();
object1.method();
console.log("New returned", object1);

// How to write a factory which can't use the new keyword?
function factory(clazz) {
    // Assume this function can't see "Class", but only sees its parameter "clazz".
    return clazz.call(); // Calls the constructor, but no new object is created
    return clazz.new();  // Doesn't work because there is new() method
};

var object2 = factory(Class);
object2.method();
console.log("Factory returned", object2);
```

Comment: Why can't you use the `new` keyword?

Comment: Daniel, in fact you can, and I incorrectly assumed I couldn't in this case. Friday afternoon fatigue, I guess ;).

Comment: J-P, so others can clarify the question if necessary.

Comment: Strangest 'still-open' and community question ever.

Comment: i have created a decorator to handle this, please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44061744/427622

Comment: See the post I added on a related thread, for details on Reflect.construct to achieve the desired result in ES6.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword#69970700.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
function factory(class_, ...arg) {
    return new class_(...arg);
}
```

I don't understand why you can't use `new`.

Comment: the stipulation was no use of "new"

Comment: Darn yes! This works great. I thought (incorrectly!) that I couldn't use the "new" keyword in this case, but of course it doesn't matter if new takes a "class" that was just defined, or if that "class" is passed in parameter to a function and the "new" is called later. Me stupid.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. All I'm getting on FF22 is "TypeError: class_ is not a constructor"

Comment: okay hot shot, how do you apply an argument list to this newly created class? ;)
new class_().apply(this,array)

i don't think so

Comment: @Lpc_dark hits the nail on the head! Maybe you could do `function factory(class_, ...args) {return new class_(...args)}` ?

Answer (score 28):

A simpler, cleaner way with no "factories"

```
function Person(name) {
  if (!(this instanceof Person)) return new Person(name);
  this.name = name;
}

var p1 = new Person('Fred');
var p2 = Person('Barney');

p1 instanceof Person  //=> true
p2 instanceof Person  //=> true
```

Answer (score 7):

If you *really* don't want to use the `new` keyword, and you don't mind only supporting Firefox, you can set the prototype yourself. There's not really any point to this though, since you can just use Dave Hinton's answer.

```
// This is essentially what the new keyword does
function factory(clazz) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.__proto__ = clazz.prototype;
    var result = clazz.call(obj);
    return (typeof result !== 'undefined') ? result : obj;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess browser independent solution would be better

```
function empty() {}

function factory(clazz /*, some more arguments for constructor */) {
    empty.prototype = clazz.prototype;
    var obj = new empty();
    clazz.apply(obj, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Dima, why is this more browser independent than the solution proposed by Dave?

Comment: cause "obj.__proto__ = something" doesn't work in all browsers
and Dave's solution doesn't support arguments for constructor

Answer (score 3):

Because JavaScript doesn't have classes, let me reword your question: How to create a new object based on an existing object without using the new keyword?

Here is a method that doesn't use "new".  It's not strictly a "new instance of" but it's the only way I could think of that doesn't use "new" (and doesn't use any ECMAScript 5 features).

```
//a very basic version that doesn't use 'new'
function factory(clazz) {
    var o = {};
    for (var prop in clazz) {
        o[prop] = clazz[prop];
    }
    return o;
};

//test
var clazz = { prop1: "hello clazz" };
var testObj1 = factory(clazz);
console.log(testObj1.prop1);    //"hello clazz"
```

You could get fancy and set the prototype, but then you get into cross-browser issues and I'm trying to keep this simple.  Also you may want to use "hasOwnProperty" to filter which properties you add to the new object.

There are other ways that use "new" but sort of hide it.  Here is one that borrows from the Object.create function in [JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742):

```
//Another version the does use 'new' but in a limited sense
function factory(clazz) {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype = clazz;
    return new F();
};

//Test
var orig = { prop1: "hello orig" };
var testObj2 = factory(orig);
console.log(testObj2.prop1);  //"hello orig"
```

EcmaScript 5 has the Object.create method which will do this much better but is only supported in newer browsers (e.g., IE9, FF4), but you can use a [polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) (something that fills in the cracks), such as [ES5 Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/), to get an implementation for older browsers. (See [John Resig's article on new ES5 features including Object.create](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/)).

In ES5 you can do it like this:

```
//using Object.create - doesn't use "new"
var baseObj = { prop1: "hello base" };
var testObj3 = Object.create(baseObj);
console.log(testObj3.prop1);
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
var factory = function(clazz /*, arguments*/) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return new function() { 
        clazz.apply(this, args)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question more literally, i.e. how to have `myClass()` return `new myClass()`... **It's not possible**, and here's why...

---

You'd have to do it like this, to make sure that the class name exists and that you're capturing calls to `myClass()` (using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) functionality, from `Proxy`/trap/handler-land):

```js
class A {

}
A.prototype.apply = function() {
  return new A();
}
A(); //Error occurs here.
```

OR:

```js
class B {

}
B.apply = function() {
  return new B();
}
B(); //Error occurs here.
```

And the reason this doesn't work is the output when you try to evaluate either of the above: `Uncaught TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'`

---

Thus, JavaScript literally does not allow it, because you have declared it to be a `class` type. However, you can of course have a separately named function that creates a new instance for you, like in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580884/1599699), or more simply:

```js
class A {

}
//Note: a != A.
function a() {
  return new A();
}
```

OR, another way to approach this problem is to **not** use a `class`, per-se, but a `function` or a regular JS object `{}`, like in the older days of JavaScript. Multiple other answers show how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

What you could also do is use `eval`.

Of course there are security concerns with `eval`, but is it really different to any other dynamic instanciation?

```
await import("/path/to/module") //use this to dynamically load module if you like
let obj = `eval new ${classname}();`
```