# JavaScript object meaning

Tags: javascript, string, object

I'm currently doing a bit of JavaScript and I have some troubles trying to explain myself one thing.

If I do that :

```
var text = new String("Enter any value here");
```

We all agree that "text" is an object, right?

But what should be "String" called then? Because I see everywhere that String is also an object, but wouldn't it be simpler to call it a class like in PhP.

Is there an other name, more precise than just object for String?

If someone can explain me the subtlety, I would be very happy. Thank you!

Comment: But a class is also an object, everything (but primitive numbers, arguably) is an object! (-insert-mad-scientist-face)

Comment: Yeah but I mean, in that case there is different "levels" of object. Why no one make it clearer by differentiating these levels with different names in JavaScript? This is absurd to me.

Comment: Because classes do not really exist in JS. Surely, you can mimic them, but that doesn't make them real. When you create an object of the type String, that is what you end up with. Anyway, you really do not need to use the new keyword for Strings, numbers, and the like. Just do `var text = 'hello'` or `var number = 1337`. More on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224295/javascript-the-good-parts-how-to-not-use-new-at-all This also covers a lot of misconception about classes in JS

Comment: because there are now class's in javascript, only objects. you are creating a new instance of an object

Comment: Yes I know all of that but I just was wondering if there was a more precise word to call it like basic objects or whatever. Because creating different objects from an object (for instance string) really lack clarity and simplicity to me. And yes I know it's better to use primitive values in this case but I just want to explain clearly JavaScript objects to someone and then I want to use the more specific and clearer word as possible.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, JavaScript (the implementation of the ECMAScript standard) has no class. So `String` cannot ever be called a class.

`String` here is but **an object**, just as almost everything in JavaScript is (as some the answers have already stated).

```
console.log(String instanceof Object); // true
```

Actually a special object: a **function**.

```
console.log(typeof String); // "function"
console.log(String instanceof Function); // true
```

And even a special function: a **function that should be called as a constructor**, hence the capital 'S'.

Even more special function: it is a built-in function (it is "present in the language" and therefore provided by the host environment -the browser or node, for example).

This special function allows you to instantiate an object of type String:

```
var aString = new String("A string");
```

But this is the wrong way to do it: you should write this:

```
var aPrimitiveString = "A string";
```

which interestingly, by the way, doesn't make `text` a String (Object), but a string (primitive).

```
console.log(typeof(aString)); // "object"
console.log(aString instanceof String); // true
console.log(aString instanceof Object); // true

console.log(typeof(aPrimitiveString)); // "string"
console.log(aPrimitiveString instanceof String); // false
console.log(aPrimitiveString instanceof Object); // false
```

Even in ECMAScript 6 (AKA ES6, AKA Harmony, AKA ES2016), there won't be any classes in the acception you have of it, "classes" in ES6 will still be an object, of type function, with **prototypal** inheritance.

One more thing: String can also be used to explicitly coerce a value into a string primitive:

```
var number = 1;

var numberAsString = String(1);

console.log(number); // 1
console.log(numberAsString); // "1"
console.log(typeof number); // "number"
console.log(typeof numberAsString); "string"
```

for the sake of completeness, I hope you guessed that:

- `number` is a **primitive number**
- `numberAsString` is a primitive string
- `new number(1)` would be an object, instance of `Number` and `Object`
- Number('0') would be a primitive number
- same goes for Boolean

There are no classes in JavaScript, there won't ever be (I don't want any of it, anyway), that is what make the language so flexible, expressive and powerful.

Maybe you would want to take a look at this: http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html (and the whole site and work of Douglas Crockford).

Answer (score 2):

I think the source of your confusion is unfamiliarity with Prototypal Inheritance model. I suppose you are well versed with 'Classical Model' where classes are constructed using Classes as blueprint. On the other hand in JavaScript other Objects are created using an Object as a prototype or using an empty object and then pinning new properties in it.

If you try logging `typeof(String)` you will get output as `function`. Here when we do a `new String('hello, world')`, we get a new String object `Hello, World`. Thus `String` is a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in JavaScript.

Comment: I suggest reading this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
It explains how we can invoke a function in different ways in JS.

Answer (score 1):

> JavaScript is an object oriented language without classes.

However, you can apply many object oriented paradigms in JavaScript. It has its own mechanisms to do so.

In JavaScript, instead of classes you use objects. That's really about it already. You can think of `String` as a class if you want, but sometimes it can lead to confusion, because it is easy to confuse concepts known from Java or C++ with JavaScript. The implementation is just different.

I suggest you omit to think of it as a class, and call it an object. And try not to apply terminology of other languages like PHP with JavaScript.

---

Now, the confusion might be that in other OO languages you define a class and then you create instances from that class, which we refer to as objects.

In JavaScript you simply *create a new copy* of another object.

Please refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and...

> ...note that JavaScript distinguishes between String objects and
>   primitive string values. (The same is true of Boolean and Numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp):

> In JavaScript, almost "everything" is an object.
>
> 1. Booleans can be objects (or primitive data treated as objects)
> 2. Numbers can be objects (or primitive data treated as objects)
> 3. Strings can be objects (or primitive data treated as objects)
> 4. Dates are always objects
> 5. Maths are always objects
> 6. Regular expressions are always objects
> 7. Arrays are always objects
> 8. Functions are always objects
> 9. Objects are objects
>
> In JavaScript, all values, except primitive values, are objects.
>
> Primitive values are: strings ("John Doe"), numbers (3.14), true,
>   false, null, and undefined.

---

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) says in javascript everything are objects.

> In JavaScript, almost everything is an object. All primitive types
>   except null and undefined are treated as objects. They can be assigned
>   properties (assigned properties of some types are not persistent), and
>   they have all characteristics of objects.

### Creating new objects

> JavaScript has a number of predefined objects. In addition, you can
>   create your own objects. You can create an object using an object
>   initializer. Alternatively, you can first create a constructor
>   function and then instantiate an object using that function and the
>   new operator.

---

So in javascript the idea of *class* doesn't really exist like in other languages. It's just an instantiated object or function if you prefer.

```
typeof 1.00 // number
typeof 1 //number
typeof "string" //string
typeof String("string") //string
typeof new String("string") //object
typeof {} //object
typeof [] //object
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/8xvge6ag/)

---

It seems possible to [create classes in ECMAScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

It is said that:

> Defining classes
>
> Classes are in fact functions, and just like you can define function
>   expressions and function declarations, the class syntax has the two
>   opponents:
>
> class expressions and class declarations.