# Prototype value not showing up in developer toolbar

Tags: javascript

If you run this in stackoverflow's code snippet, it displays both first and last names, but on my website, when using Chrome's developer toolbar or Firefox it only displays the firstName property.

```js
    function Person(){
      this.firstName = 'first name goes here';
    }

    var person = new Person();
    Person.prototype.lastName = 'last name goes here';
    console.log(person);
```

I also have a nagging suspicion that using the "new" keyword is considered to no longer be a best practice, but I can't recall where I might have read that.

Comment: Yep, different tools give different outputs. Nothing strange about that. The SO snippet overrides the default behaviour of `console.log`.

Comment: *"I also have a nagging suspicion that using the "new" keyword is considered to no longer be a best practice, but I can't recall where I might have read that."* Don't let yourself get confused by ideologists. There is nothing wrong with `new`.

Comment: @trincot: Make it an answer :)

Comment: [This is basically what `new` does](https://jsfiddle.net/xmv97187/). It seems to me that purists believe it would make more sense to explicitly write this out every time... it's up to you.

Comment: the "lastName" is a property with a shared value among all objects of type "Person". this behavior doesn't shock me.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, different tools give different outputs. Nothing strange about that. The SO snippet tool overrides the default behaviour of `console.log`, creating a virtual console.

#### Background of the Stack Snippet Virtual Console

After the Stack Snippet was launched, this became one of the change requests from the user community: [Add a console to Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets), which eventually was implemented: [Stack Snippets Upgrade: Virtual Console](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console).

The discussion in those threads on meta show why this was a desired feature, for example:

- It's a lot of work to realize that there's no output because we haven't opened the console.
- you see people using `document.write`, which is just a terrible idea.
- `alert()` is extremely intrusive.

This implementation is quite different from what `console.log` would produce in the browser's console, which in itself is ambiguous: different browsers have different console behaviours: there is no standard as to what should be output in the console. Notice for example the many difference between FireFox and Chrome when doing `console.log(new Set([1]).entries());`

#### Differences

The Stack Snippets virtual console shows all enumerable properties, whether they are inherited or not. This roughly corresponds to this:

```
for (prop in person) {
    console.log(prop, person[prop]);
}
```

Consoles in browsers have a more comprehensive rendering. Apart from the collapsible controls and the asynchronous retrieval, they also visualise non-iterable properties, like `__proto__`. Inherited properties are then listed when that `__proto__` node is expanded. All these features are much more advanced than the light Stack Snippet solution.

If you would like to know the precise reason for why inherited, enumerable  properties are included in the virtual console output, then that question is better suited for [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), where the designers (@canon and others) can comment on their decisions themselves.

## Use `new`?

Concerning the use of `new` is best practice or not: this is mostly opinion based. You may have a look at [JavaScript: The Good Parts - How to not use `new` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224295/javascript-the-good-parts-how-to-not-use-new-at-all): you can see how the most-voted answer swings between the two.

Comment: this answer doesn't quite satisfy me though!

Comment: In what way? What did you expect?

Comment: For example: Why &quot;engineers&quot; decided not to do this ??? Or why this is the way it is! You are basically confirming that this behavior exists! Not quite satisfying!

Comment: *Why* it was done the way it is in the Stack Snippet Virtual Console is really a question that is better suited to be asked on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com). See the update to my answer.