# smart javascript jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, i find this really amusing, and of course, if i were to dive into the code a little further more than this, i would of surely know how they manage to do it. What i'm talking about is JQuery library. Take a look at the code below -

```
 $.prototype.mymethod=function(str){
    alert(str);
}

//now call the added method
$(document).mymethod('hello') //alert out hello
```

If `$` is a pure normal javascript function
(not using jquery library), the added method wont work as expected unless the `new` keyword is prepended before `$`

```
new $(document).mymethod('hello')
```

But with JQuery, `new` keyword is very optional!

Can someone give more insights into it as to how they did it without me having to go through their library?

EDIT:
After a hard struggle, finally I dug out the actual root mechanism of how the above works (constructing a
JavaScript object
without using the `new`
keyword)! I believe this will serve as a good futere reference for anyone desiring to learn advanved javascript!

```
function a(){
    return a.prototype;
}
a.prototype.fn=function(){
    alert('hello')
}

a.prototype.test=123;

console.log(a().test)//123 
a().fn()//alerts out hello
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) :

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

The `new` is already called when you call `$(document)`.

If you want to do the same thing the jQuery way, here's how it can be :

```
var A = function(str){
    return new A.prototype.init(str);
}
A.prototype.init =function(str){
     this.str = str;
     return this;
};
A.prototype.init.prototype = A.prototype;

A.prototype.f = function(arg){ // add your function
   console.log(this.str+' '+arg);
};
A('hello').f('world'); // logs "hello world"
A('bye').f('bye'); // logs "bye bye"
```

Comment: @spaceman12: There is nothing special about it. Just create a function which, when called, creates a new object and returns it. For example: `function A() { return new B(); }`.

Comment: But if i want to add method to `A` and not B, and call it as A().mymethod() , how would you return the new created object for A?

Comment: Wouldn't `A().mymethod()` call `mymethod` on whatever is returned by A, not A itself? I think it you want to return a new object for A you would need `A.mymethod()`, which will return a new created object for A if `mymethod` creates one...

Comment: @spaceman12: If you want to create a new instance of `A` without calling `new`, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889014/can-i-construct-a-javascript-object-without-using-the-new-keyword). Note though that this is not what jQuery is doing.

Comment: @spaceman12 I edited with an exemple of how to reproduce jQuery's trick.

Comment: thanks all for the help. The edits made by @dystroy is very helpful. However, i just posted in as edits in the question a much better and simpler one just in case if there are any js enthusiast desiring to learn more :)

Comment: @spaceman12: The "problem" with your solution is that you are always returning the same object. You won't be able to access any arguments passed to `a` as function.

Comment: of course, if i want any arguments be passed into the constructor function, i can modify it but thats just plain easy 

function a(obj){
    return new a.init.init(obj)
}
a.init=a.prototype={
init:function(obj){
alert(obj)
return this;
}
}
And much more