# How to implement function newObject that would act exactly like new operator?

Tags: javascript, prototype, new-operator, apply

How to implement function `newObject`(without using `new` operator inside) that would act exactly like new operator? (in javascript)

To be precise I want `obj = new MyClass(arg1, arg2)` to be the same as `obj2 = newObject(MyClass, arg1, arg2)`

Any ideas, because I'm out of ideas? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889014/can-i-construct-a-javascript-object-without-using-the-new-keyword

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6750880/1048572 and linked questions

Comment: This is also worth seeing http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/new-operator.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to build is called a factory ,is a common design pattern i would advice you to red through these

http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/factory-method-design-pattern

https://carldanley.com/js-factory-pattern/

so you have a better understanding on what you are about to do