# How to enforce a JavaScript constructor?

Tags: javascript

I have the following constructor:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age  = age;
}
```

Now if I say:

```
var p = new Person("jon", 25);
```

It will create an instance of `Person` but what if a user does the following:

```
var p = Person("jon", 25);
```

This will lead to `name` and `age` being defined on the `window` object.

My question is, is there a way to prevent the user from calling `Person` directly without `new` and thus not allowing `window` object to be augmented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way around it using a scope safe constructor:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  if (this instanceof Person) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  } 
  else {
    return new Person(name ,age);
  }
}
```

Read more: [New/Scope Safe Constructors in OO JavaScript](http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/9-new-scope-safe-constructors-in-oo-javascript)

Comment: that's pretty cool stuff, living learning :)

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly test for the condition:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  if (!this || this === window)
    return new Person(name, age);
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

Now, that still doesn't prevent somebody from doing something like

```
var obj = {};
Person.call(obj, "John", 22);
```

You can test with `instanceof` as in another answer, which deals with that problem:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  if (!(this instanceof Person))
    return new Person(name, age);
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

Comment: Can't you test for (!(this instanceof Person))? So that prevents everything?

Comment: @StrandedKid testing with `instanceof` is the best thing to do - I should edit the answer.

Comment: this is basically correct but see mine below for a more simple form

Answer (score 1):

See [Can I construct a JavaScript object without using the new keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1889014/218196)

This doesn't prevent the function from being called without `new`, but calling it with or without `new` will have the same effect.

---

If you want the function to only be constructable (i.e. "callable" with `new`), you have to look at ES6 and declare a class:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Constructor functions that are created from the `class` syntax *must* be called with `new`. Otherwise an error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(name ,age){
    if ( ! (this instanceof Person) ) {
        return new Person(name, age);
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;
}
```