# Why do immutable.js classes not require "new"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

For example, this is perfectly fine code.  (The style is ES6)

```
import {List} from 'immutable';

console.log(List()); // List []
```

However, this fails.

```
class Foo {}

Foo(); // TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

Further, this fails, too.

```
class Foo extends List {}

Foo(); // TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

Comment: Probably because they're not constructed using `class`? Or the ES6 transpiler was in loose mode.

Comment: In what environment are you executing this, which `immutable` version are you using?

Comment: `immutable` version is 3.7.5

Comment: I think your call on the transpiler is probably where it's at.  Will keep investigating and report back if I find anything :)

Comment: I believe I've enabled loose mode, but to no avail.  Seems to fail, like above.  I'm using `babelify` 6.3.0 for transpiling (under the covers, it's `babel` 5.8.24).

Comment: Looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to stop investigating.  I like the workaround provided here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31789308/1438285

Comment: The answer didn't work for me.  I think I'm resigned to "new" :(

Comment: You mean the workaround does not work? What is the problem?

Comment: I had issues with it when I extended `List`.  I'm guessing it was related to the transpiling, but didn't investigate further.

Comment: Ah, thanks for testing. Right, that's likely problematic, I edited my answer there. However, transpilers don't really support `Reflect` or `new.target`, so you have to ensure that you `extends List` before overwriting `List` with the new-less function. Or use `… extends _List`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the magic for `immutable` happens in their custom addon to the transpiler [here](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/resources/declassify.js).

They're basically creating their own `createClass` which skips the check.  This is a snippet from the transpiled (via `babel`) version of my code above.

```
var Foo = (function (_List) {
  _inherits(Foo, _List);

  function Foo() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Board);

    _get(Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype), 'constructor', this).apply(this, arguments);
  }

  return Foo;
})(_immutable.List);
```

Where `_classCallCheck` looks like this.

```
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function');
    }
}
```

For `immutable`, it seems the ES6 code is first transformed to already include the `createClass` calls.