# Factory function in a Typescript declares file, with and without the new keyword

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5

The following code will create a factory function in ES5:

```
function MyClass(val) {
    if (!(this instanceof MyClass)) {
        return new MyClass(val);
    }

    this.val = val;
}
```

This function can be called with or without the `new` keyword:

```
var a = new MyClass(5);
var b = MyClass(5);
```

This works fine in Typescript, however I can't figure out how to create a declares file with [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) that describes both behaviors. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason you'd want that? I mean, I get that it works, but is there a reason why you don't just say "I'm going to define that from now on, in TypeScript, this is only a `new`able object", and define it as such? These static factories are mostly confusing, and don't really help with any actual abstraction.

Comment: There's a few different arguments, the main one is that forgetting the `new` keyword is a common source of bugs, but they're all arguable. But to more directly answer your question, this is a declares file that is describing an existing library for which removing the factory signature is a breaking change. This may change in the future, but it can't now. There's actually another SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/32807163/907125) that asks about doing this IN Typescript, but they suggested that I repost it specifically for declares.

Comment: That's fair, I've given it a shot yesterday and couldn't do it, so ping me in two days of you don't get an answer and I'll post a bounty on it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
interface MyClass {
  val: {};     
}

interface MyClassConstructor {
  (val: {}): MyClass;
  new (val: {}): MyClass;
}

declare const MyClass: MyClassConstructor;
```