# constr.apply(this, args) in ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, constructor, ecmascript-6

I have used the following function to create instances of unknown classes for some time:

```
Kernel.prototype._construct = function (constr, args) {
  function F() {
    constr.apply(this, args); // EXCEPTION!
  }
  F.prototype = constr.prototype;
  return new F();
};
```

If I use prototypes everything works:

```
function Person(name, surname) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
}

var person = Kernel._construct(Person, ["name", "surname"]); // WORKS!
```

However, some people are using my library using ES6 native classes in node v4+:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}

var person = Kernel._construct(Person, ["name", surname]); // EXCEPTION!
```

They are getting an error:

```
TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I need to be able to invoke the constructor with an unknown number of arguments. Any ideas about how to get around this issue?

Comment: What's the purpose of `_bind` in your code?

Comment: I have removed, it was there because I was testing using _bind...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are various ways you can do that:

1. Using [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Methods) object's methods:

   ```
   Kernel.prototype._construct = function (constr, args) {
     return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(constr, [null].concat(args)));
   };
   ```

   Here we're [applying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) `args` as arguments for [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). The goal is to have a function that can be called without arugments so that we can call `new x()`. `bind` does this for us, but we need to set it up correctly. The syntax is:

   ```
   func.bind(thisArg[, arg1][, args2...])
   // calling the results from the above is like
   // thisArg.func(arg1, arg2...);
   ```

   We want to use `constr` as the function to bind, and the items in `args` as the arguments. We don't care about `thisArg`. To do that, we need to "convert" the `args` array to arguments. The `apply` call does that:

   ```
   func.apply(thisArg[, args]);
   // calling the results from the above is like
   // thisArg.func(args[0], args[1]...);
   ```

   `apply` is actually calling `bind`. The first item,`[null]`, is important because we want to call `bind` where `thisArg` is `null`- like this: `constr.bind(null, args[0], args[1]...)`.
2. Using ES2015 [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

   ```
   Kernel.prototype._construct = function (constr, args) {
     return new constr(...args);
   };
   ```

   This is much simpler, but there are 2 problems:

   1. It requires ES2015 support, and even the latest Node (v4.2.1) requires a flag for this (*--harmony_spreadcalls*).
   2. This will generate a syntax error if not supported, and you can't even do that conditionally, other then using dynamic scripting (`eval()` / `new Function(...)`) - which is not advised.
3. Using the [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) built-in in object.

   ```
   Kernel.prototype._construct = function (constr, args) {
       return Reflect.construct(constr, args);
   };
   ```

   This is also simple, but is even further behind in terms of support (basically you *must* use babel).

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer, option one solved my issue :)

Comment: It should be noted that 1 will work for native classes only with native `Function.prototype.bind` implementation. If accidentally replaced with polyfill, TypeError will still be thrown (transpiled classes are ok with any implementation).

Comment: Great answer. Solution 1 is really killer and was only option for me

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this by binding the arguments to the function and then calling new on it:

```
Kernel.prototype._construct = function (constr, args) {
  var F = constr.bind(null, args);
  return new F();
};
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but your solution is inaccurate. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Good question, but **no**, you cannot call constructors without the `new` keyword in ES6 according to [ECMAScript §9.22](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget).

I asked an identical question here:
[ES6: call class constructor without new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword)

> I need to be able to invoke the constructor with an unknown number of arguments. Any ideas about how to get around this issue?

Well this says nothing about (not) using the `new` keyword, but you can easily use variadic arguments in an ES6 constructor

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, surname, ...others) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.others = others || [];
  }
}

let p = new Person('OweR', 'ReLoaDeD', 'a', 'b', 'c');
p;
//=> {"name":"OweR","surname":"ReLoaDeD","others":["a","b","c"]}
```

I suspect this isn't what you're after. But, if you're trying to avoid using `new` to invoke a class in ES6, it cannot be done.

---

So, with that said, what are you actually trying to accomplish ?