# Node.js require class with constructor parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class

```
class advertHandler {
    constructor(projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    getProject(name) {
        return this.projects[name];
    }
}


module.exports = new advertHandler(projects);
```

When I try to use it like this

```
const advertHandler = require('./advertHandler')(projectsArray);
advertHandler.getProject('test');
```

And it throws an exception, `require is not a function`, but without a constructor, everything is fine, so the question is how to use the class constructor with require?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not saying `require` is not a function, it's saying `require(...)` is not a function. :-) You're trying to *call* the result of `require(...)`, but what you're exporting (an instance of `advertHandler`) isn't a function. Also note that in `advertHandler.js`, you're trying to use a global called `projects` (on the last line); ideally, best not to have globals in NodeJS apps when you can avoid it.

You just want to export the class:

```
module.exports = advertHandler;
```

...and then probably require it before calling it:

```
const advertHandler = require('./advertHandler');
const handler = new advertHandler({test: "one"});
console.log(handler.getProject('test'));
```

E.g.:

advertHandler.js:

```
class advertHandler {
    constructor(projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    getProject(name) {
        return this.projects[name];
    }
}

module.exports = advertHandler;
```

app.js:

```
const advertHandler = require('./advertHandler');
const handler = new advertHandler({test: "one"});
console.log(handler.getProject('test'));
```

Comment: Is it possible to do in single line? something like 

`const advertHandler = new require('./advertHandler')({test: "one"});`

Comment: @A-letubby: Yes, but it's less readable: `const handler = new (require('./advertHandler'))({test: "one"});` (note the `()` around the `require` call).