# Dynamically attaching ES6 Object's methods from One object to another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, component-design

I have this basic component class that looks like this

```
class Component {
    constructor() {
        this.manager = null;
    }
    behavior(){
        //some behavior
    }
}
```

I want an instance of GameObject to dynamically inherit that behavior by doing something like

```
var myGameObject = new GameObject();
myGameObject.attach(myComponent);
```

so that I can easily do

```
myGameObject.behavior();
```

Is this possible through ES6? if not what other alternatives do I have?

Comment: `Object.assign(this, myComponent)`

Comment: @4castle this only copy over the object's properties, not any methods

Comment: It is possible to copy over the methods, but [as seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword) you can't invoke `Component`'s constructor on an arbitrary object, so ES6 classes may throw up some hurdles in your attempt to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found a way to do this, but not sure if this is just bad practice

```
attach(component){
   Object.assign(this,component);
   while (component = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(component)) {
     if(component == Object.prototype) break; // no need to redefine Object
     let keys = Reflect.ownKeys(component)
     for(var i=1;i<keys.length;i++){
       Reflect.getPrototypeOf(this)[keys[i]] = component[keys[i]];
     }
   }
   return this;
}
```