# What is the reason ES6 class constructors can't be called as normal functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

ES6 class constructors can't be called as normal functions. According to ES6 a `TypeError` should be raised when this is done. I used to think that classes were just syntactic sugar for a constructor function + functions in the prototype, but this makes it slightly not so.

I'm wondering, what was the rationale behind this? Unless I missed something, it prevents calling the function with a custom `this`, which could be desirable for some patterns.

Comment: Maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword

Comment: This question is probably opinion based, but likely so you don't forget to call it with *new*. Better to ask on a TC39 discussion forum somewhere.

Comment: Same reason they can't be called as functions in pretty much every other OOP language? Because that's not what constructors are for?

Answer (score 0):

A revisit to the ES6 spec shows *how* calling a Class function object without new is disabled by combining sections 9.2.9 and 9.2.1:

> 9.2.9 MakClassConstructor (F)
>   ...
>   3. Set F’s [[FunctionKind]] internal slot to "classConstructor".

and when specifying the [[call]] method as opposed to the [[contruct]] method of a function:

> (9.2.1) 2. If F’s [[FunctionKind]] internal slot is "classConstructor", throw a TypeError exception.

No restrictions are placed on calling function in section "11.2.3 "Function calls" of ES5.1.

So you are not missing anything: you can't use `apply` on a class constructor function.

The major rationale is probably both to make class extensions a fairly rigorous exercise, and to detect some early forms of error. For example you can't call `Promise` except as a constructor - and leaving out `new` before a call to `Promise` *is* a programming error. In regards extending classes, note that the `constructor` property of class instances is correctly set (the last class after possibly multiple extensions) and the the `.prototype` property of the class constructor is read only - you can't dynamically change the prototype object used to construct class instances, even though you could change the prototype property of a constructor function.

I used to think classes were syntactic sugar but have moved away from the concept.

Answer (score 0):

To recap, your two main points are

1. > ES6 class constructors can't be called as normal functions.
2. > It prevents calling the function with a custom this

The first thing to note is that from the standpoint of the runtime behavior of a class, those are to points are not functionally tied together. You could for instance allow `Foo()` without `new` but still have `Foo.call({})` behave like it had been `new`ed. The ability to call as a function *can* allow setting `this`, but it doesn't have to, the same way `Foo.bind({})()` would bind a `this` and then call the function, but the bound `this` would be ignored.

For the rationale behind the decision, I can't give you a primary source, but I can tell you there is one solid reason. ES6 class syntax is "syntax sugar", but not for the simplified code you likely have in your head. Take for example this snippet, given your goal.

```
class Parent {}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    // What is "this" here?
    super();
  }
}

Child.call({});
```

What should this do? In ES6, `super()` is what actually sets `this`. If you try to access `this` before having called `super()`, it will throw an exception. Your example code *could* work with `Base.call({})` since it has no parent constructor, so `this` is initialized up front, but as soon as you're calling a child class, `this` doesn't even have a value up front. If you use `.call` there is no where to put that value.

So then the next question is, why do child classes not get `this` before `super()`? This is because it allows ES6 class syntax to extend builtin types like `Array` and `Error` and `Map` and any other builtin constructor type. In *standard* ES5 this was impossible, though with the non-standard `__proto__` in ES5 it could be simulated *roughly*. Even with `__proto__` it is generally a performance issue to extend builtin types. By including this behavior in ES6 classes, JS engines can optimize the code so that extending builtin types works without a performance hit.

So for your questions, yes, they could allow `Foo.call()`, or `Foo()`, but it would have to ignore `this` either way in order to allow for extending builtin types.

Answer (score 0):

> what was the rationale behind this?

It's a safeguard. When you called an ES5 `function` constructor without `new`, it did very undesirable things, failing silently. Throwing an exception helps you to notice the mistake.

Of course they could have opted for the call syntax to just work the same as construction, but enforcing the `new` keyword is a good thing that helps us to easily recognise instantiations.

> It prevents calling the function with a custom `this`, which could be desirable for some patterns.

Yes, this is what fundamentally changed in ES6. The `this` value is initialised by the superclass, which allows subclass builtins with internal slots - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458960/1048572) for details. This conflicts with passing a custom this argument, and for consistency one must never allow that.

Comment: Btw, a few desirable patterns can still be realised using `Reflect.construct`. What in particular are you looking for?