# Is there a way to allow a class constructor to be invoked as if it were an ordinary function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, new-operator, mixins, es6-class

I'd like to dual-purpose an ES6 class constructor as a mixin function.

I have a simple class with a few methods. A simplified example:

```js
class foo {
    constructor() {}

    hi() { console.log('hello'); }
}
```

In most cases I create instances of this class:

```js
let bar = new foo();
bar.hi(); // hello
```

Sometimes it's used as a superclass:

```js
class baz extends foo {
    constructor() { super(); }
}

let bar = new baz();
bar.hi(); // hello
```

But, as the methods can work independent of anything else, it would be nice if I could use the constructor as a mixin, like so:

```js
class foo {
    constructor( mixin ) {
        if ( !new.target ) { // not called with `new`
            if ( !mixin ) throw new TypeError( 'Must supply mixin' );
            mixin.hi = foo.prototype.hi;
            return mixin;
        }
    }

    // ...
}

let bar = {}; // this could be instance of another class, whatever.
foo( bar ); // Class constructor foo cannot be invoked without 'new'
bar.hi();
```

That's the problem I run in to. Constructors can't be invoked as if they were just a normal function.

Is there any way to stop the constructor from throwing an error when invoked without `new`, without reverting to an ES5 approach of building classes?

I tried wrapping the class in a normal function, and using `new.target` (my env is ES6) to detect when `new` is being used:

```js
function Goo( mixin ) {
   if ( new.target ) return new foo();
   if ( !mixin ) throw new TypeError( 'Must supply mixin' );
   mixin.hi = foo.prototype.hi;
   return mixin;
}

let goo = new Goo(); // I get a new instance of foo
goo.hi(); // hello

let bar = {};
Goo( bar );
bar.hi(); // hello
```

...but quickly realised that:

```js
class oof extends Goo { // ugh
```

Also, I'd have to clone `static` stuff from `foo` on to `Goo`, which is meh.

As a fallback I currently use a static `mixin()` method on the `foo` class:

```js
class foo {
   static mixin( target ) {
      if ( !target ) throw new TypeError( 'Must supply target' );
      target.hi = foo.prototype.hi;
      return target;
   }
   // ...
}

let bar = {};
foo.mixin( bar ); // Well, it's semantic at least
bar.hi(); // hello
```

But I'm keen, even just to see if it can be done, to have something that works in these three scenarios:

```js
let ifoo = new foo();
ifoo.hi();

class woo extends foo { /* ... */ }
let iwoo = new woo();
iwoo.hi();

let bar = {};
let ibar = foo( bar );
ibar.hi();
```

Anyone up for seeing if it's do-able, even if it probably shouldn't be done?

Comment: No, it's not possible, but you can [make the `Goo` wrapper approach work with subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789308/1048572).

Comment: Sounds like a reverse [`Reflect.construct()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [snippet posted by Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword/31789308#31789308), I came up with the following function: `altEgo()`.

It creates a `mask` function, behind which sit an `alt` (used for normal invocation) and `ego` (used for `new` instances). It checks `new.target` to decide whether to use `alt()` or `new ego()`. You can also `extends` the `mask`.

```js
// to add an alter ego to fooFn:
// fooFn = altEgo( altFn, fooFn );

function altEgo( alt, ego ) {

    if ( typeof alt !== 'function' ) throw new TypeError( `alt must be a function` );
    if ( typeof ego !== 'function' ) throw new TypeError( `ego must be a function` );

    const mask = function( ...args ) {
        return new.target ? Reflect.construct( ego, args, new.target ) : alt( ego, mask, ...args );
    }

    for ( const property of Object.getOwnPropertyNames( ego ) )
        if ( altEgo.always.has( property ) || !mask.hasOwnProperty( property ) )
            Object.defineProperty( mask, property, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( ego, property ) );

    return mask;
}
altEgo.always = new Set([ 'name', 'length', 'prototype' ]); // properties to copy to mask
```

This works successfully with all three scenarios mentioned at end of OP.

Here's a testbed in which the `ego` function is `class foo`. As you can see, the masked `foo` works just like the original when it's used as a class and can even be extended by the `woo` class. Instances of `foo` and `woo` behave as expected, and statics also work. If you invoke `foo` like a normal function, the `alt` kicks in.

```js
'use strict';

class foo {
    static chk() {
        console.log(`static ${this.name}.chk()`);
    }

    static get getchk() {
        console.log(`static ${this.name}.getchk`);
    }

    constructor( a, b, c ) {
        this.con = true;
        console.log(`new ${new.target.name}()`);
    }

    check() {
        console.log(`${this.constructor.name} inst.check(); inst.con = `+this.con);
    }

    get getcheck() {
        console.log(`${this.constructor.name} inst.getcheck`);
    }
}

console.dir( foo );

function altEgo( alt, ego ) {

    if ( typeof alt !== 'function' ) throw new TypeError( `alt must be a function` );
    if ( typeof ego !== 'function' ) throw new TypeError( `ego must be a function` );

    const mask = function( ...args ) {
        return new.target ? Reflect.construct( ego, args, new.target ) : alt( ego, mask, ...args );
    }

    for ( const property of Object.getOwnPropertyNames( ego ) )
        if ( altEgo.always.has( property ) || !mask.hasOwnProperty( property ) )
            Object.defineProperty( mask, property, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( ego, property ) );

    return mask;
}
altEgo.always = new Set([ 'name', 'length', 'prototype' ]); // properties to copy to mask

let alt = function( ego, mask, target ) {
    console.log( 'alt function' );
    for ( const property of alt.clone )
        Object.defineProperty( target, property, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( ego.prototype, property ) );
    return target;
}
alt.clone = new Set([ 'check', 'getcheck' ]);

foo = altEgo( alt, foo );

console.dir( foo );

console.log('foo =====================================');

foo.chk();
void foo.getchk;
let ifoo = new foo;
ifoo.check();
void ifoo.getcheck;

console.log('woo =====================================');

class woo extends foo {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

woo.chk();
void woo.getchk;
let iwoo = new woo;
iwoo.check();
void iwoo.getcheck;

console.log('bar =====================================');

let ibar = foo( {} );
ibar.check();
void ibar.getcheck;
```

Note: I also investigated the potential for using [`Proxy` with a `construct` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct) but wasn't able to get it working due to lack of `new.target`.