# Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Hero cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, class

Reviewing this great [tutorial: Understanding Classes in JavaScript](https://www.taniarascia.com/understanding-classes-in-javascript/) by Tania Rascia, I encountered this error while going over how you can [extend a class](https://www.taniarascia.com/understanding-classes-in-javascript/#extending-a-class).

```
class Hero {
  constructor(name, level) {
    this.name = name
    this.level = level
  }

  // Adding a method to the constructor
  greet() {
    return `${this.name} says hello.`
  }
}

// Creating a new constructor from the parent
function Mage(name, level, spell) {
  // Chain constructor with call
  Hero.call(this, name, level)

  this.spell = spell
}
```

> VM3527:4 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Hero cannot be invoked
>   without 'new'
>       at new Mage (:4:8)
>       at :1:15

This **will** work as expected when using a function without the `class` keyword.

```
function Hero(name, level) {
  this.name = name;
  this.level = level;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6: call class constructor without new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is descriptive of itself, a constructor cannot be invoked without attempting to create a new instance of it.

```
var myHeor = new Hero(name, level);
```

The only methods you can call without creating an instance are the [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) methods