# What is the difference between instanceof Parent and instanceof super.constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, instanceof

I got a class `Parent`, and a class `Child` extending `Parent`.
In `Parent`'s constructor I need now to determine if `x` is an instance of the original class or of the child class.

As in my case `Parent` is actually anonymous I'm using `instanceof of this.constructor` which isn't working as expected:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(x) {
    if (x instanceof this.constructor) {
      console.log("x is instanceof of this.constructor");
    }
    if (x instanceof Parent) {
      console.log("x is instanceof of Parent");
    }
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(x) {
    super(x);
  }
  foo(x) {
    new this.constructor(new super.constructor(x))
  }
}
```

Calling

```
new Child().foo()
```

now yields `x is instanceof of Parent` but not `x is instanceof of this.constructor`. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this without using `x is instanceof of *Parent*`?

---

The reason for all this is that I'm wrapping my class definition so that I can create a new instance without `new`. The class is assigned to `Parent` after wrapping/mutating, so the class that is wrapped should be anonymous.

I don't know if that makes any sense, and my reduced example may fail to make clear what's the point of all this, but apart from the one issue explained above it's actually quite handy:

```
X()   // create new instance of Parent without new
X.f   // access static methods
```

```
const { X, c: Parent } = function (c) {
    return {
        X: Object.assign(
            function () {
                return new c(...arguments);
            },
            _.pick(c, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c)  // using lodash here
                .filter(n => typeof c[n] === "function")
            )
        ),
        c
    };
}(class {
  constructor(x) {
    if (x instanceof this.constructor) {
      console.log("x is instanceof of this.constructor");
    }
    if (x instanceof Parent) {
      console.log("x is instanceof of Parent");
    }
  }
})

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(x) {
    super(x);
  }
  foo(x) {
    new this.constructor(new super.constructor(x))
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `this.constructor` is `Child` not `Parent`. --- Also, `super.constructor` isn't used in the example

Comment: "*in my case Parent is actually anonymous*" - just fix that problem so that you can write `instanceof Parent`, which is what you want and would work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hm yes, got something wrong there; should be fine now

Comment: Please show us your actual code with the anonymous class and why you need that to solve your actual problem. Given your previous question, it seems this approach causes nothing but problems.

Comment: This sounds like really questionable design. What is the real-world situation that led to this?

Comment: @Bergi I was expecting this... I finally added some more code

Comment: Please don't blame me if you think it's rubbish

Comment: I really recommend just using `new`.

Comment: But I explicitly need to get an instance of Parent so I need to use super, and `new super` is not working

Comment: So `instanceof Parent` would work. But you ideally would want to write `instanceof X` if I understood you correctly? Of course, even currently nothing prohibits you from writing `const X = (c => { … })(class local { constructor(p) { if (p instanceof local) console.log("got Parent/X instance"); } });`

Comment: "*I'm wrapping my class definition so that I can create a new instance without new.*" - that's a pretty basic wrapping, and I don't understand why you only copy static methods. You'll want to have a look at [the tricks shown/mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789308/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I think I will finally stick to the [local] approach; in the end it's acutally shorter and more concise, and it solves my problem

Comment: @Bergi And thanks for the reference, I think I will also refine my wrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the bindings of `Parent` and `Child` identifiers are the Parent and Child class constructor functions and constant. When used as the first parameter of `Object.assign`, the `Parent` binding has not been created **but** while methods are being assigned to function `c`, the  function is not actually called. So when it comes to calling class constructor code later, both `Parent` and `Child` variables refer to the appropriate class constructor.

Hence

```
class {
  constructor(x) {
    if (x instanceof Parent) {
      console.log("x is instanceof of Parent");
      if( x instance of Child) {
      console.log("x is instance of Child");
    }
  }
}
```

should indicate if the parameter is an instance of `Parent` or `Child`. Of course because  the class extension puts `Parent.prototype` at the head of `Child.prototype`'s inheritance chain, every instance of `Child` it is also an instance of `Parent`.

The results obtained from code examining `instanceof` values are as to be expected:

1. `foo` creates an `[Object Parent]`  object parameter to pass to the `Child` constructor
2. `Child` calls the super constructor with the supplied parameter taking the form:

   ```
     super([Parent Object])
   ```

   *but with the `this` value seen by `super` set to the new `Child` object instance.*
3. In the super constructor the `[Object Parent] x` argument is not an instance of `this.constructor`, which is `Child`, so no message saying so is generated.

You may wish to see if the full code could be simplified by using less complexity, along the structural lines of:

```
 class Parent {..........}
 class Child extends Parent {.....}
 const X = Object.assign(.......)
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it clear to me. I understand that I should not do this as a one liner, the only (pedantic) concern I have is that I do think of X and Parent as of the same thing (and Parent is actually only stored because it's needed for Child definition) and struggle in naming them seperately.

Comment: My point is, I initially designed the wrapping function to not even return the Parent definition but to hide it completely; but I guess even then it doesn't hurt to locally assign a name, like [local] suggested above.