# How to properly use Function's construct signatures in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm reading TS documentation, when I read [*More on Functions*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), I don't understand the code below, how to use it in actual development. Are there any examples?

```
interface CallOrConstruct {
  new (s: string): Date;
  (n?: number): number;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see here is *a single object that has different behavior depending on whether you call it with `new`*. This is something Javascript is capable of doing, but can lead to confusing code; you'll probably see that kind of signature only very infrequently, or when adapting a *very* old or flexible Javascript library for Typescript usage.

(Technically, the behavior doesn't have to be different: Sensible objects might be callable with or without `new` with the same overall behavior, and would require both *call* and *construct* signatures. However, this kind of deliberate flexibility is still unusual. Thanks @kaya3!)

---

Your snippet appears in *More on Functions* under the text:

> Some objects, like JavaScript’s `Date` object, can be called with or without `new`. You can combine call and construct signatures in the same type arbitrarily:

This is a reference to the built-in Date object, which has [this text on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#constructor):

> `Date()`
>
> > When called as a function, returns a string representation of the current date and time, exactly as `new Date().toString()` does.
>
> `new Date()`
>
> > When called as a constructor, returns a new `Date` object.

```js
console.log(typeof Date())      // string
console.log(typeof new Date())  // object
```

As said above, it is very uncommon that a single Function object will serve both purposes: You'll usually see a function/class deliberately called as one or the other, but not both. However, because it is possible to do in Javascript (and even done in built-in objects) it is important for TypeScript to be able to represent an object that works in both call styles.

```js
interface CallOrConstruct {
  new (s: string): Date;      // construct
  (n?: number): number;       // call
}

// construct
let object: Date = new CallOrConstruct("optional string s");

// call
let myNumber: number = CallOrConstruct(/* n= */ 42);
```

You probably won't need to ever type out an interface like this, especially if you use `class` and `constructor` for classes and `function` (or other normal function declarations) for your functions. You'll only need to do so if you're trying to declare types TypeScript doesn't understand (as in a [`.d.ts` TypeScript declarations file for an external Javascript library](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)) or if you're trying to write a clever and confusing TypeScript object that can used in both ways. Speaking for myself, I haven't had a reason to write my own declaration like this, though I've read a few in libraries and their typings.

Comment: OK, Thank you!! In addtion, I also want to ask a question, how this Interface works on functions or classes(I don't know where to put it!)

Comment: More commonly (and more sensibly), you can write a constructor in such a way that it can be called with or without `new`, with the same signature either way. In that case it's still necessary to use an interface with both a call signature and a constructor signature.

Comment: @OnlyWick You probably won't need to ever type out an interface like this, especially if you use `class` and `constructor` for classes and `function` (or other normal function declarations) for your functions. You'll only need to type out an interface like this if you're trying to `declare` types TypeScript doesn't understand (as in an external Javascript library) or if you're trying to write a clever and confusing TypeScript object. Speaking for myself, I haven't had a reason to write my own declaration like this, though I've read a few in libraries and their typings.

Comment: @kaya3 This is true, and I can edit in a line about that, but I posit that even the sensible objects that let you call either way are relatively rare and are unlikely to be relevant to a TypeScript/Javascript newcomer.

Comment: @OnlyWick See e.g. [ES6: call class constructor without new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword). And yes, this is rare and you absolutely won't need to write any of your own code like this, it's more an issue if you are working with third-party code which does this kind of thing.