# Make JS class callable without side effects

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, class, prototype

For context, I am trying to re-create the native `Date` object to better suit my purposes, for this I am extending it with a class, for a basic example:

```js
class MyDate extends Date {
  constructor(...input) {
    super(...input);
    this.change = 'example change';
    return this;
  }
}
```

In most ways I have succeeded at my task, my `NewDate` class works nicely, and almost fully matching in behavior with the native `Date` class, however it has one little difference:

```js
console.log(Date()); // this works, printing your current date as a string
console.log(MyDate()); // doesn't work, gives the error below:
// Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor MyDate cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

So how can I replicate `Date`'s behavior of being both a class constructor and a function at the same time? Obviously it is possible otherwise `Date` wouldn't be able to do it.

I have already tried:

- Messing with prototypes (`.prototype` and `.__proto__`) although there's so many ways to tamper with those I wouldn't be surprised I missed some very obscure caveat with them.
- Making a function called `MyDate` which returns the string or my class constructor, which actually does work but breaks `new MyDate instanceof Date` (since it becomes an instance of a Function instead)
- Every top answer on this question: [How to extend Function with ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871299/how-to-extend-function-with-es6-classes) | They all worked in some way but broke in another.

Comment: ES6 `class`es are not callable, only constructable. You need to use ES5 `function` syntax in order to define classes that are both callable and constructable.

Comment: I'm assuming just using `new MyDate()` wont work for. you?

Comment: Closely related [ES6: call class constructor without new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30689817/364696). I see a hint of an answer in the existence of `call constructor`s in newer versions of the standard mentioned in the comments, but don't know anything about 'em.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789308/1048572) should do. No, you don't want to `extend Function`.