# Instancing class with an without new with a class decorator

Tags: typescript, constructor, decorator

Looking for ways to instantiate classes without new in typescript, this fine answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061744/430531
works nicely in javascript.

The code in the repo referred https://github.com/digital-flowers/classy-decorator is a simple class decorator:

```
var classy = function classy() {
    return function (Class) {
        var _Class = function _Class() {
            for (var _len = arguments.length, rest = Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
                rest[_key] = arguments[_key];
            }

            return new(Function.prototype.bind.apply(Class, [null].concat(rest)))();
        };
        _Class.prototype = Class.prototype;
        return _Class;
    };
};
```

But using it under Typescript like this:

```
@classy()
class Someone{
    constructor(private name: string){}
}
debugger
let some1 = new Someone("john");
let some2 = Someone("joe")  // some2 is also an instance of Someone! but typescript complains that it's not callable
```

I have yet to dig into the function decorator itself to understand it well and that also has ts errors but is operational.

But I wonder if there's a way to avoid the Typescript error when instancing without new (`let some2 = Someone("joe")`)

Comment: Decorators don't mutate types in TypeScript, see [ms/TS#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881), so while you can apply a decorator to `Someone`, it doesn't change the type of `Someone`.  The workaround here is usually to just call your decorator like a function.  [Here is an example](https://tsplay.dev/mpnaBw).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) don't mutate the types of the things they decorate in TypeScript.  That means the `Someone` constructor will not be seen by the compiler to have a call signature.  There is a longstanding feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) to support class decorator mutation at the type level, but it's been stuck in limbo for a long time waiting for the [proposal for adding decorators to JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) to be approved.  It's now at Stage 3 of [the TC39 process](https://tc39.es/process-document/), and [microsoft/TypeScript#48885](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48885) is tracking implementing JS conformant decorators in TypeScript, but I don't know when or if type mutation will be implemented.  For now, this is just not possible.

---

The main workaround here is to calling the decorator as a regular function, since function outputs are able to be different in type from their inputs.  For example, we could make a `tsClassy` function which we [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to behave as something that takes a constructor as input and returns a callable constructor as output:

```
const tsClassy = classy() as
  <T, A extends any[], R>(ctor: T & (new (...args: A) => R)) => T & { (...args: A): R };
```

In order to use it, we can't just decorate `Someone`.  Instead we must call it on a class constructor and save the output to its own variable.  Perhaps like this:

```
const Someone = tsClassy(class Someone {
  constructor(public name: string) { } 
});
//const Someone: typeof Someone & ((name: string) => Someone)
```

Now the compiler sees `Someone` both as a class constructor and as a callable function:

```
let some1 = new Someone("john");
// let some1: Someone
console.log(some1.name) // john 

let some2 = Someone("joe");
//let some2: Someone
console.log(some2.name) // joe
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&filetype=ts#code/G4QwTgBAxgNiDO8CeEC8EBmBXAdlALgJYD2O0ciSAFAJQQDeAsAFAQRgCm+WYZ2eRUhCoBhCvABcEEDiR0mrNhFCQA+mITw0mXARJl142gxZKlGYpCoqIqmBzLpwAcywBbB-ngA6ezmf4ABYANOwc8PjaAIJgYCDUdg40oaoA1hwo6AAMANy26SgAPLZ+eWkZANQV8qZmSpwRANrlSAC62i7unvDNBa05tWYAviyD9Vw8ZDgcAO7CAGK6gjjeAA5gxPibSKsc3gBGhDgAJt4gq6sw1BqIoY04WDAwrd5QpFAg+FQN+HQI0rIaDRaANFGwhqCzIZNGsNlt8DsONobj51pttrtIeNuLxbCisRCWCNmCw3jgIhAvCjMuRNNQ-vBaoUACqhKIQDgAD3wDmOWhkSEarVCACUAHxUAiWKTMiAAMmE0zmVG8qpckggUToqDFEBFQLQutlCvowlVZzAzg1WqkIoghJJjrJFIAysQPKQkegqeJqLBNBA3R7piZFM78GAsFKwFRVlh9jBCFAIDgQB4pBEwEdnPJ7RAAPT5iCBEDHSnECBuEDpSmBQhaOMJpMQfYcD5YeBIpDELAAck40BL-mztaRxzbcDiyyJNFBhfDgfdHE9UgRu2IGEXwaRCqoVFT6Ygmez2t1QeX0xoo2Y9ki8CXAEZtEqtxeOFQAEQAK2IgRwH9nFhCwgW8j0fKRz09UlSHvexfGIZwqHvDwH28A8ODoYCfz-CBr1A5COAAJm0SDpk-H8OAAud83wpdCIgpcoOYZ1iDgmAEKQui0LTDCCyLCjr0Ex0hJE4SxNEiTxKkySZLEoA)