# Is it possible to instantiate a class without a `new` operator?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, new-operator, es6-class

Is it possible to instantiate a class without a `new` operator?

With the constructor functions, I can use `new.target` do something like this:

```
function Person(name) {
  if (!new.target) {
    return new Person(name);
  }
  this.name = name;
}

let p1 = new Person("John");
let p2 = Person("Jack");
```

This will create an instance of `Person` without a `new` operator. Is there a similar way to create an instance of a class without `new`?

The code below throws `TypeError: Class constructor Person cannot be invoked without 'new'`.

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    if (!new.target) {
      return new Person(name);
    }
    this.name = name;
  }
}

let p2 = Person("Jack");
```

Comment: No. It doesn't matter, it's just the syntax of the language

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't seem to be working". It doesn't run? It errors? It produces unexpected output? I suspect there's a very specific error message happening that will answer your question.

Comment: @CollinD, I've edited the question. Yes, it throws a specific error which I'm trying to bypass

Comment: Do you ask our of curiosity or do you have a real use case for this?

Comment: I wonder if this is a duplicate of [ES6: call class constructor without new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689817/es6-call-class-constructor-without-new-keyword)

Comment: Here's the spec explaining why calling w/o new is erroring. https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist

Comment: The language does not permit what you're asking for.  You can create your own separately named factory function such as `createPerson()` that will do the `new` for you if you really don't want the caller to have to do it.